# Динамическое создание Button

Tags: android

Создаю динамически кнопки. 
С разным текстом и разными Drawable.
Текст у всех кнопок разный, а Drawable почему-то берется последний присвоенный для всех кнопок. В чем проблема?

```
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Button LessonButton = new Button(this);
        LessonButton.setText(LessonsList[i]);
        LessonButton.setId(i);
        LessonButton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        if(recPoint[dayNumber][i]==0){
            LessonButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.red_stars_static,0);
        }
        if(recPoint[dayNumber][i]==1){
            LessonButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.green_stars_static,0);
        }
        if(recPoint[dayNumber][i]==2){
            LessonButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.orange_stars_static,0);
        }

        llMain.addView(LessonButton, lParams);
    };
```

Comment: Какие значения в recPoint[dayNumber]?

Comment: Мне кажется или все созданные таким образом кнопки - один и тот же объект (изменения в одном из них приводят к изменениях во всех "клонах") ? PS: в Java имена экземпляров класса  принято писать с маленькой буквы.

Comment: @lsillarionov recPoint[0][0,0,0,0,0,1],recPoint[1][0,0,0,0,0,0]

Comment: @pavlofff Мне вот тоже так кажется, но почему тогда setText для каждой кнопки разный? А где у меня имя класса с большой буквы?

Comment: Не имя класса, а имя экземпляра класса (объекта). У вас `Button LessonButton` - в Java принято писать `Button lessonButton`. `lessonButton` - экземпляр класса `Button`, класс `Button` - с большой буквы, экземпляр класса  (объект) `lessonButton` - с маленькой.

Comment: @lsillarionov Вы правы... что-то не так с recPoint...

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в формировании массива recPoint, динамически кнопки создавались правильно.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.